# When i run app extension(Widget) in device.I got this error App installation failed

Tags: ios, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique.

Comment: Are you using the same bundle identifier for both application & Extension?

Comment: Yes.If i give different bundle id how to manage provisioning profile

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If your application bundle identifier is com.companyName.productName then your extension bundle identifier should be com.companyName.productName.extensionName

If you assign the bundle identifier in this way then your provisioning profile will work for both.

Comment: I solved that issue using two separate provisioning certificate for two bundle id which should be used in application & app extension.Now it's working correctly.Thanks for your help iphoneDeveloper39

Comment: @iphoneDeveloper39 -- Can u explain little bit, bz I am not get the answer

Comment: So that means i need to create 2 Bundle Id for both frameworks. Or alternate is to create 2 provisioning files ?

Comment: @Meenakshi, do we need to create two provisioning profiles i.e one for app and other for extension?

Comment: Yes, you need to create 2 provisioning profile. one for app another for extension using same certificate.

Comment: How many provisional profile create ?. App or Extension both .

Comment: You are a legend

Answer (score 0):

My bundle ID's were ok but I had to change some settings in my provisioning profiles to fix this error

Comment: What are the changes you done in provisioning profiles ?

Comment: I'm not sure which action leaded to the fix but I think switching to non-wildcard provisioning profiles fixed it

Answer (score 0):

*You Bundle Identifier Should Look Like*

1) Main Project---> com.CompanyName.ProjectName

2) NotificationService(ExtensionName) ---> com.CompanyName.NotificationService

3) NotificationContent(ExtensionName) ---> com.CompanyName.NotificationContent

Answer (score -1):

You will have to create two provisioning profile.

After you create the first one ending in product name... download and install

Then create another one like the first profile, ending with .Extension (like .Meme) ... download and install

If you build after the two steps above the Error might still appear.

Then go to the General where you have the bundle id ... add the .Extension (add it to what you have there like blahblahblah.Meme)

Then you will get an error and a suggestion to "Fix issues" ... 
Click on "Fix issues" and allow it to finish.

Then you should be able to build successfully and install. This is how it
worked for me.